# How can I remove manually added event listeners on beforeDestory hook of one component before redirecting to any another component, in Vuejs2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, lifecycle-hook

I want to know the concept of the below thing-

I have created one component and set up its respected event listeners. Now, I want to remove those listeners on this component's beforeDestroy hook before redirecting to another route that will create another component.
but what I noticed is, beforeDestory hook of the first component is calling even after the second component's created hook.

I want to destroy the first component completely and then create another component.

```
// To set up the event listeners
created() {
  this.EventBus.$on('myCustomEvent', payload => {
    // some code here
  )}
}

// To destroy the event listeners
beforeDestroy() {
  this.EventBus.$off('myCustomEvent');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

### In search of an answer to your question, I came to the conclusion that it is better to refuse to use EventBus altogether.

Here is some [information](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/strange-behavior-when-using-events-and-vue-router/10129/4) on this and [some](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/#comment-1423) thoughts from there:

> I have that feeling that having an EventBus in Vue is an anti-pattern, especially if you’re using VueX but I can’t quite put my finger on it. At the point you want to be sharing data like that, wouldn’t it be better to use a store to handle all of those “events” / “mutations”?

Also, looking at the solution to this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1181), you are doing everything right and there is no other way.